# Graphical login does not start properly at boot time after upgrade from Squeeze to Wheezy

Tags: debian, xorg, amd-radeon, ati-mobility-radeon, debian-wheezy

At boot time, KDM (or XDM or LightDM) fails with Xorg error: `no screens found`.
But a manual restart using `service kdm restart` seems to fix it.

### Xorg errors

```
[    17.551] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.551]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    17.551]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[    17.551] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    17.551] (II) RADEON(0): TOTO SAYS 00000000f6df0000
[    17.551] (II) RADEON(0): MMIO registers at 0x00000000f6df0000: size 64KB
[    17.551] (II) RADEON(0): PCI bus 1 card 0 func 0
--
[    18.832] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[    18.832] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 9
[    18.832] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:01:00.0
[    18.832] (EE) RADEON(0): [dri] RADEONDRIGetVersion failed because of a version mismatch.
[dri] This chipset requires a kernel module version of 1.17.0,
[dri] but the kernel reports a version of 2.12.0.[dri] Make sure your module is loaded prior to starting X, and
[dri] that this driver was built with support for KMS.
--
[    18.832] (II) Unloading int10
[    18.832] (II) UnloadSubModule: "vgahw"
[    18.832] (II) Unloading vgahw
[    18.832] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    18.832] 
Fatal server error:
[    18.832] no screens found
```

### Additional info

As you can notice, I have an ATI Radeon. Earlier on Debian Squeeze, I was using the proprietary ATI driver. Just switched to the free driver after the upgrade and it has been like this since.

Any idea how to fix this for good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "switched" to using the open drivers, did you **uninstall** `fglrx` (the proprietary driver)? It overwrites parts of the graphics stack that are depended on by the open source graphics stack. The upgrade might not have replaced all the components that `fglrx` muddies up.

> [dri] This chipset requires a kernel module version of 1.17.0,
>   [dri] but the kernel reports a version of 2.12.0.

A few things to try:

- Make sure no files such as /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf contain any lines such as `blacklist radeon` or `install radeon /bin/true`.
- Try reinstalling or making sure that the package `glx-alternative-mesa` is installed and that `glx-alternative-fglrx` is uninstalled
- Reinstall/install `libgl1-mesa-dri` and `libgl1-mesa-glx` and `libglapi-mesa` and `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` and `xserver-xorg-core`
- Triple check that you **ran the AMD fglrx (Catalyst) uninstaller**... if you did not run the installer then remnants of fglrx could still be messing up your install. On the other hand, if you installed the proprietary driver using the `fglrx-driver` package, do `aptitude purge fglrx-driver`.
- Make sure you are booting the Wheezy kernel and not the old Squeeze kernel. The Wheezy kernel may be lower priority in the GRUB boot list, but you need to boot the Wheezy kernel to use the Wheezy graphics stack, so just check your GRUB menu boot order and boot the "newest" kernel version you have available.

Comment: Those lines are there:
`fbdev-blacklist.conf:blacklist radeonfb
fglrx-driver.conf:blacklist radeon`
What can be done about that? I don't suppose simply removing them help?
How do I run the `fglrx` unintsaller?
Reinstalled and uninstalled the other said packages. Didn't help.
Kernel is 3.0 itself. Not using the old one.

Comment: As long as `blacklist radeon` is in fglrx-driver.conf, you aren't going to get working X with the open source graphics drivers. It's now fully obvious to me that you **did not** remove fglrx the correct way, and that pieces of it are strewn throughout the system. I don't know *how* you installed it, though. If you installed it through a download on AMD's website, you need to run **that same download file** and pass the correct command line to uninstall. If you installed a Debian package, uninstall (and purge) that package. Also, kernel 3.0 is from Squeeze; Wheezy uses 3.2.

Comment: The next thing you'll probably complain about is that running `./fglrx-blah-blah-omg-long-command-name.run --uninstall` complains that some of its files are missing. The `--help` option is useful. It says you can pass `--force` to uninstall anyway. If that doesn't work, you may have to dig deeper and try other commands... again, self-discovery via `--help` is the best way.

Comment: I had installed the proprietary drivers by referring this: https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary/#Squeeze . So purging the `fglrx-driver` worked. Everything is working now (although purging `fglrx-glx` failed).